# Make SFDC Org Read ONLY?

Tags: salesforcedx

We are in mid of an merger & acquistion Project and we intend to de-provision the acquired company SFDC Instance. Is there any way to make an Org Read ONLY without deactivating users?

While talking to Salesforce Support, it seems that they will transfer licenses - will that remove the need of deactivating the users as there aren't any licenses?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you still want to retain the Org and want a Read Only access for Users in that Org or completely deactivate the Org?

Comment: You can make the majority of the users read only by creating a profile that has read only access to all objects and assigning all users (except an admin) to it.

Comment: @JasonHardy There is already a profile for that. It's called Read Only.

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't believe you can adjust that one for custom object's as I recall. It's been a while since I've worked with that one, but I think that's why most of the org's I've worked with in the past have had to use custom read only profiles.

Comment: Read ONLY Profile makes complete sense here & that was my target but it consumes a SFDC License. The plan is to remove license dependency from the ORG. 

Another option was to change the license to Salesforce Platform but folks from SFDC keep on using the word "We can make the ORG Read ONLY". I didn’t found any documentation for this except for maintenance windows. So I was wondering if anyone has gone through this Salesforce Making Org Read ONLY Process during an old M&A Project.

Comment: *The plan is to remove license dependency from the ORG* -- as long as you have an active user in the org, you have a license consumed. You get a license available only if a user is inactive. If your users still want to access the org someway or other, you cannot relinquish the licenses.

Comment: Licenses aren't "transferred" at a technical level. Salesforce.com typically just provisions licenses in the destination org, and after you migrate, they delete the source org. There's no need to free up licenses unless you're told to do so.

Comment: having done this before, you can get SFDC to extend access to seats (gratis or near gratis) during a transition period of org migration